# Where to run jQuery after ember template renders?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

With Views deprecated, I'm having trouble discerning where to run jQuery after a Template has rendered.

I have a simple index Template for a foods resource (templates/foods/index.hbs), and wish to run the following jQuery after index.hbs renders:

```
this.$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

I know one can create a Component that then has a `didInsertElement` hook, but I'm not clear on how I'd route to the Component if I did this. Would I then "double dip" by having my `apps/templates/foods/index.hbs` Template simply call the new Component, which would have its own template that would be the original `index.hbs` Template?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here. Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call jQuery in route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    didTransition() {
      Ember.run.next(this, 'initTooltip');
    }
  },
  initTooltip() {
    Ember.$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  }
});
```

You can also create component and use it inside your template like this:

```
{{tooltip-wrapper}}
  <!-- HTML here -->
{{/tooltip-wrapper}}
```

And call jQuery code in `didInsertElement` of `tooltip-wrapper` component.

Comment: This works, but it seems a little wonky that one has to call Ember.run.next. Is there really no direct "after" type callbacks for when a template has finished rendering? Going to keep this up for a little bit to see if there is a more conventional way before marking as answered.

Comment: There's a didRender hook now.

Comment: @ChristopherMilne I found said hook on Components after a bit of digging, but I'm still unclear on the correct approach to using a component for something like an index route. Would the "double dipping" strategy I mentioned in my question be correct?

Comment: Your index.hbs template will be nothing more than a shim for the component. In other words that template will contain the component and nothing else

Comment: Unfortunately +1 for the 'double dipping' strategy - just create a landing-page component.